# File manager with auto-renaming of files and strict validation

Tags: php, file-management

I'm looking to develop a file manager which has some slightly unusual requirements. The idea is that an authenticated user can upload new files, re-order existing ones (through drag and drop), and delete - nothing new here I know. However, the files are being used as part of a media presentation and have a strict ordering and naming convention, so I'd thought I'd let them upload files with any name, then do the renaming on the fly, at which point I can determine what the name should be, in line with what already exists in a folder. Basically, every change which is made has a potential knock on effect for all file names within a folder. Added to this, I want to set up a versioning system with the option to roll back to previous states.

I'm probably leaning towards a PHP and jQuery solution, hopefully by building on top of something which is already out there. Is there anything out there which is likely to work well with me adding extra validation and processing on top of standard file manager processes? It doesn't have to be PHP, this intranet site will only be running on a handful of machines with the same spec. Possibly there could be a solution to this via Java or another language...

Hope this isn't too vague, just hoping someone might have experience of a file manager which could integrate with what I'm going to have to do.

Comment: For a photographer or something like this ? ^^

Comment: It's for a media presentation, so all the images have to be high-res. The files are being used by an application written in Director - I just need to make sure that the images can be updated without messing up the presentation!

Comment: You have a lot of solution such as Diaspora, 280Slide or by yourself http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/news/create-a-photo-admin-site-using-php-and-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

I would use a stack like data structure to save the state of the editing:

`push --> add new action to the history (eg new slide added)`

`pop an element out of the stack --> rollback to the previous change`

At the end of the editing, the user press the `commit` button and the PHP will read the stack and only at this time the files will be renamed in the correct way